# Python - Check if json array has multiple objects

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse data from an output from a router, however sometimes two duplicate values. Because of this, I need to check for 3 possibilities, one MAC, two MACs and no MAC.

This is what I currently have:

```
            else: #Starts the parse
                parser5 = ttp(output5, template_05_ad)
                parser5.parse()
                #put result in JSON format
                results_0 = parser5.result(format='json')[0]
                #str to list **convert with json.loads
                result_0 = json.loads(results_0)

                #Places the results into variables
                if 'mac' in result_0[0][0]:
                    mac_connected = str(result_0[0][0]['mac'])
                elif 'mac' in result_0[0]:
                    mac_connected = str(result_0[0]['mac'])
                else:
                    mac_connected = 'NULL'
```

With outputs looking like the following:

```
One MAC:
                                                             CE 
Vlan     Mac Address       Type        Interface      CTag  Vlan
----  -----------------  ---------  ----------------  ----  ----
4065  E1:B4:19:64:1B:51  Dynamic    10/0/1@1/2/2      na    na  
Total MAC addresses for this criterion: 1

Two MAC:
                                                             CE 
Vlan     Mac Address       Type        Interface      CTag  Vlan
----  -----------------  ---------  ----------------  ----  ----
4065  E1:B4:19:64:1B:51  Dynamic    10/0/1@1/2/2      na    an  
4065  E1:B4:19:64:1B:51  Dynamic    10/0/1@1/2/2      na    na  
Total MAC addresses for this criterion: 1

No MAC:
No MAC addresses found for this criterion
```

When it gets parsed it will look like this (printed output from `result_0`):

```
One MAC::
[{'mac': 'E1:B4:19:64:1B:51'}]

Two MAC:
[[{'mac': 'E1:B4:19:64:1B:51'}, {'mac': 'E1:B4:19:64:1B:51'}]]

No MAC:
[{}]
```

Sorry if this has been answered before, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: when you read the json, can you print the output and share it so we can see the json format?
`result_0 = json.loads(results_0)`
`print(result_0)` <--

Comment: I did that for the section about what it looks like when it gets parsed, so that will be the json format, I should've probably said that was the printed output

Comment: So do you want to avoid duplicate mac addresses in case there are two of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you either get a list of dictionaries or a single json dictionary as value for `result_0[0]`.

You can simply check whether it is a list first. Since you are always only interested in the first mac value, you can just work with the first list element in that case. If you then use the `.get()` method with a default value, you do not need to treat the empty case as separate:

```
            else: #Starts the parse
                parser5 = ttp(output5, template_05_ad)
                parser5.parse()
                #put result in JSON format
                results_0 = parser5.result(format='json')[0]
                #str to list **convert with json.loads
                result_0 = json.loads(results_0)

                if isinstance(result_0[0], list):
                    result_0[0] = result_0[0][0]

                #Places the results into variables
                mac_connected = result_0[0].get('mac', 'NULL')
```

(this assumes that in the list case, the mac result you want in the end is always in `result[0][0]`)

Another option might be to adjust your TTP template in a way so it always returns a list (even if there is only one element in it) in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I forgot to say what output I wanted with this, but this lines up with what I wanted. I did add a bit to get the mac when it is one by itself, but it now all works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how you would like the data returned, but this could maybe help you getting closer to a solution?

```
def CheckMAC(mac):
    connected_mac = ""
    for value in mac:
        if value:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                return(value['mac'])
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for nested_value in value:
                    connected_mac += f"{nested_value['mac']} "
                return(connected_mac.strip())
        else:
            return("NULL")

oneMAC = [{'mac': 'E1:B4:19:64:1B:51'}]
twoMAC = [[{'mac': 'E1:B4:19:64:1B:51'}, {'mac': 'E1:B4:19:64:1B:51'}]]
noMAC = [{}]

print(CheckMAC(oneMAC))
print(CheckMAC(twoMAC))
print(CheckMAC(noMAC))
```

Results:

```
E1:B4:19:64:1B:51
E1:B4:19:64:1B:51 E1:B4:19:64:1B:51
NULL
```